# Proving conjecture on number series

Tags: programming, theorem-proving

I have a conjecture that Stephen Lucas's identities for Pi and its convergent could be generalized as follows:

```
(-1)^n*(Pi - A002485[n]/A002486[n]) == (Abs[i]*2^j)^(-1)*Integrate[(x^l*(1 - x)^(2*(j + 2))*(k + (i + k)*x^2))/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, 1}]
```

where integer $n>2$, $(n = 3,4,5,...)$ serves as the index for the corresponding terms in [OEIS A002485](https://oeis.org/A002485)(n) and [A002486](https://oeis.org/A002486)(n) integer sequences and ${i, j, k, l}$ is the specific set of four integer parameters (to be found experimentally or otherwise) corresponding to the specific value of n.

The integral yields the following [expression](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XDXUANFtVG-PJDsWqCUjaG-UWCT0I5gO)

Originally I found by visual observation and fitting that above is satisfied for cases covered by Stephen Lucas research:

for $n=3$ with $i=-1$, $j=0$, $k=1$, $l=4$;

for $n=4$ with $i=265$, $j=1$, $k=197$, $l=5$;

for $n=5$ with $i=791$, $j=2$, $k=25$, $l=8$;

for $n=6$ with $i= -47201$, $j=4$, $k=124360$, $l=14$;

Here are references for Lucas work:

http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2005/Sep05/Lucas.pdf

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267998655_Integral_approximations_to_p_with_nonnegative_integrands

[http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper141.pdf](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Emikeh/webpapers/paper141.pdf)

This issue was also posted by me several years ago on https://math.stackexchange.com, particularly: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860499/seeking-proof-for-the-formula-relating-pi-with-its-convergents

and on

https://mathoverflow.net, particularly: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175762/is-formula-valid-for-relating-pi-with-all-of-its-oeis-a002485n-a002486n-c

In some of the posted answers it was shown that: there is an infinite multitude of {j,j,k,l} solutions for each of A002485(n)/A002486(n) Pi convergents and that in order to have just a single solution for each of A002485(n)/A002486(n) Pi convergents the number of parameters should be reduced from four to two.

Above is confirmed experimentally by the found by Maxima program (which uses brute force trial and error) solutions as follows:

$$ n = 2 ==> ( -1 -1 1 1)

n = 2 ==> ( 5 1 79 1 )

n = 2 ==> ( -105 3 15703 1)

n = 2 ==> ( 3003 5 3265501 1)

n = 2 ==> ( -17017 7 117197427 1)

n = 2 ==> ( 323323 9 12938569465 1)

n = 2 ==> ( -26558675 11 5822357747957 1 )

n = 2 ==> ( 145568097675 13 167497581760018981 1 )

n = 2 ==> ( -14325749295 15 83748791323596173 1)

...

n = 2 ==> ( 37825425 16 11338429672808230471587052268612747 36)

...

n = 3 ==> (-21 0 1 0)

n = 3 ==> (-5 1 1 1)

n = 3 ==> ( 105 3 137 1 )

n = 3 ==> ( -3003 5 29219 1 )

n = 3 ==> ( 17017 7 1046413 1)

...

n = 3 ==> ( -113476275 16 32102060152077381820091 12)

n = 3 ==> ( 429 -1 283 13)

n = 3 ==> ( 16445 11 13836450782495167 13 )

n = 4 ==> (318 0 -13 0)

n = 4 ==> (265 1 197 5)

n = 5 ==> (-339 0 14 0)

n = 5 ==> (791 2 25 8)

n = 6 ==> (47201 4 124360 14)

n = 7 ==> (-2409 4 1349 12)
n = 8 ==> ( -66317 -1 9977 1 )

n = 8 ==> ( -6963285 3 212651 1 )

n = 8 ==> ( -66383317 7 833127 1)

n = 8 ==> ( -103605391175 11 720252257 1 )

n = 8 ==> ( -55884747999795 15 517817918873 1 )

n = 8 ==> ( -66317 0 8805 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -2188461 4 89050 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -16380299 8 317214 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -1305427928805 12 23297755114 2)

n = 8 ==> ( 896546759355 14 27371124886 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -23756674250925 16 5393931750178 2 )

n = 8 ==> ( -66317 1 8246 3)$$

The only pattern which could be seen looking on all currently available i,j,k,l data is that $[j - l]$ is congruent modulo 2, which means that the difference between the values of j and l, denoted as (j - l), is divisible by 2. However, I don't know what to do with this data - I don't visually see any other simple pattern helping to reduce the number of parameters from 4 to at most 2.

**Does Mathematica have any commands/package helping to find out the pattern based on this type of data?**

**When n->infinity then A002485(n)/A002486(n)->Pi while the integral component will approach value of 0. So may be the way to strengthen or to disproof my conjecture is to see whether there exists the set of i, j, k and l under which integral, and consequently, the resulting expression consisting of hypergeometric and gamma functions attains the value of zero (0)?**

**How *Mathematica* could be used to efficiently find solutions for $n>6$?**

**Could *Mathematica* be used for proving above conjecture in general?**

Comment: I have helped with some formatting and a more descriptive title, but the OP (that's you Alex) needs to [edit] the question to improve it or risk having the question closed. As it stands, the questions shows no diligence and is too broad and focuses on maths issues. Please share you code attempts, including the implementations for `A002485[n]` and `A002486[n]` and narrow down your question to a specific programming task.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The questions typically asked and answered on this site are of the structural kind (perhaps with a bit of application details thrown in); meaning that you have already figured out an algorithm and you have tried a few things using Mathematica and now you either want to remove any errors or achieve better performance etc. Questions involving Math proofs are often migrated to the ]Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: putting this into Mathematica language: I believe `(-1)^n*(Pi - A002485[n]/A002486[n]` is the same as as `(-1)^(n) (Pi - Last@Convergents[Pi, n - 1])` for n= 3,4,... Also, not sure if it helps or you already know this, but the integral can be solved by Mathematica...

Comment: ...`Integrate[(x^l*(1 - x)^(2*(j + 2))*(k + (i + k)*x^2))/(1 + x^2), {x, 
  0, 1}, Assumptions -> 
  j \[Element] Integers && k \[Element] Integers && 
   l \[Element] Integers && j >= -2 && l >= 0]`

Comment: @David Trimas - Thanks. I placed reference (link) to the snapshot (which is kept on Google drive with access to everyone) of the expression which comes out as the result of integration. Could you see it and if yes - is the expression the same as you got?

Comment: @Alex yes they are the same

Comment: Here's a link to my notebook where I checked if they're equal https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dtrimas/Published/checkIntegralsAreEqual.nb

Comment: @David Trimas - According to the visual observation all so far experimentally found  {i,j,k,l)  integer solutions for the convergents are such that                                                            [l - j] = 2*m                                                                            (I don't know if plugging this relation into discussed resulting expression will give some additional insight into the issue).  Also what do you think of examining whether equaling this expression to zero  is possible and under what values of {i,j,kl}?

Comment: @Alex The integral result looks like constant*2^-(stuff)*Gamma stuff * hypergeometric stuff. Constant*2^-(stuff)*Gamma stuff will never be zero on the positive integers so the only places it would be zero is where the hypergeometric part is zero. The only roots of the integral I've found are for i=k=0. I don't know if finding the roots of the integral is helpful though.

Comment: I tried implementing the rule replacement /.l->2m + j and also /.l->2+j (I.e. m =1) but I didn't get any additional insight from it. I also tried adding it as an assumption with FullSimplify: `FullSimplify[integral, Mod[l,2]==Mod[j,2]]` but it didn't change the result

Comment: @David Trimas - Thanks! With regards to "The only roots of the integral I've found are for i=k=0. I don't know if finding the roots of the integral is helpful though" I think since when n->inf A002485(n)/A002486(n)->Pi and that is only possible (if my conjecture holds to be true) when integral part ->0 then for some large n one should see the values of i and k to both decrease approaching 0...?

Comment: Yes unless there is another root where i and k are not 0. Sorry, I made that realization that the integral must go to 0 when n goes to infinity, but then I completely forgot about it when I said it wouldn't be helpful to find the roots of the integral. If there is another root that isn't the i=k=0 case, I am not sure how to find it though.

Comment: @Alex there is also the `Abs[i]` part in front of the integral so there are also zeros where i=0 and k= something else.

Comment: @David Trimas - yes, you are right - Thanks!

Comment: I added a solution to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I have not found a pattern yet (**update: look at edit 2, I have found a general pattern**), just a simplification by setting some parameters to 0. It's not really what you asked for since I am reducing the solution space by setting those values to 0, but it at least makes solutions easy to generate. I am reposting my response from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/13uewjh/comment/jm3f0oy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) here as others may be able to expand on this:

I cannot think of a way to get Mathematica to find a pattern for {i,j,k,l} as a function of n, but I have found a simplification for the rhs of `(-1) ^ n * (Pi − A002485(n)/A002486(n)) = ((Abs(i)) * 2 ^ j) ^ (-1) * Int((x ^ l * (1 - x) ^ (2 * (j + 2)) * (k + (i + k) * x ^ 2 ))/(1 + x ^ 2 ), x=0 ...1)` by only looking at solutions with j=l=0:

```
integrand = (x^l*(1 - x)^(2*(j + 2))*(k + (i + k)*x^2))/(1 + x^2);

int = Integrate[integrand, {x, 0, 1},Assumptions ->i \[Element] Integers && j \[Element] Integers &&k \[Element] Integers && l \[Element] Integers && j >= -2 &&l >= 0 && Mod[l, 2] == Mod[j, 2]];

rhs = FullSimplify[(Abs[i]*2^j)^(-1)*int];

lhs[n_] := (-1)^(n) (Pi-Last@Convergents[Pi, n - 1]); (*for n>=3*)
```

bring `(-1)^(n)` over to other side, multiply by -1 and add Pi. This should be equal to `Last@Convergents[Pi,n-1]` now

```
rhsShifted = FullSimplify[Pi + rhs*(-1)^(-n + 1)];
```

this function is usefel as it is now the lhs of our equation

```
lastConvergent[n_] := Last@Convergents[Pi, n - 1];
```

`rhsShifted` looks like:

```
\[Pi] + (1/
 Abs[i])(-1)^-n 2^(-7 - 3 j - l) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   Gamma[5 + 2 j] Gamma[
   1 + l] (-4 k HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, (1 + l)/2, (2 + l)/
       2}, {3 + j + l/2, 1/2 (7 + 2 j + l)}, -1] - (i + k) (1 + 
       l) (2 + l) HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, (3 + l)/2, (4 + l)/
       2}, {4 + j + l/2, 1/2 (9 + 2 j + l)}, -1])
```

examining the structure of rhsShifted, there's a lot of j and l stuff out front. To simplify it, let's just look at solutions with j=l=0:

```
rhsShifted = FullSimplify[rhsShifted /. {j -> 0, l -> 0}]
```

now `rhsShifted` is quite a bit simpler:

```
\[Pi] - ((-1)^-n (3 k + i (-47 + 15 \[Pi])))/(15 Abs[i])
```

lets test with n=8 to see if we get a solution:

```
trial = lastConvergent[8] == FullSimplify[rhsShifted /. n -> 8];

trialSoln = First@FindInstance[trial, {i, k}, Integers];

newRule = Join[{j -> 0, l -> 0}, trialSoln];

(*test solution*)

FullSimplify[(rhs /. newRule ) - lhs[8]]
```

This ends up being 0, so lhs=rhs with our solution for n=8. Let's write a general function to find solutions as a function of n:

```
eq := lastConvergent[#] == rhsShifted /. n -> # &

findRule :=Join[{j -> 0, l -> 0},First@FindInstance[eq[#], {i, k}, Integers]] &
```

testing up to n=200. Norm is 0 if they are all 0 (i.e. equal):

```
Norm@Table[Chop@N[(rhs /. findRule[ii]) - lhs[ii]], {ii, 3, 20}]
```

This finds a solution for all values of n I've tested (up to n=200) and is relatively fast (~0.005s for n=400).
plot up to n=400 to see linear growth in computation time:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[findRule[ii];], {ii, 3, 400}]]
```

[image]

I also plotted the solution values for i and k, and you can see they are nearly linear in log space as a function of n, indicating an  almost-exponential-law relation between n and {i,k}:

```
IKrules = {i, k} /. Table[findRule[ii][[-2 ;; All]], {ii, 3, 400}];

iRules = IKrules[[All, 1]];

kRules = IKrules[[All, 2]];
```

(The absolute value of i and k are nearly linear in log space as a function of n, indicating some kind of exponential equation can approximate the solutions. I Use abs because both i and k switch sign for each sucessive n, so really it's something like a (-1^(n+offset)*exponential equation))

```
ListLinePlot[{Abs@iRules, Abs@kRules}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"n", "value"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> 12, Black, 
   Bold}, PlotLegends -> {"Abs[i]", "Abs[k]"}]
```

[image]

Finally, I noticed that i/k rapidly approaches a constant, so you can write i as a linear function of k i=a*k and now you only have to solve one variable k for large enough n:

```
ListLinePlot[(iRules/kRules), Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", "i/k"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> 12, Black, 
   Bold}, PlotRange -> {All, {-24.5, -24}}]
```

[image]
One thing you could now, is utilize FindSequenceFunction[] to attempt to find a solution separately for i and k as a function of n. But I haven't had luck with this yet.

Edit: all plots as a function of n are really a function of n-2 since we start at n=3 and I am plotting lists of data starting at index 1. But I don't have the motivation right now to go back and fix my plots.

Edit 2: I tried to look at solving `rhsShifted` for a function of n `f[n]`. `f[n]` here is really the nth Convergent of Pi (`lastConvergent[n]`) but I can't put that into our equation to solve because I don't know an equation for the n-1th convergent of Pi:

```
FullSimplify[Solve[f[n] == rhsShifted, {i, k}, Integers]]
```

yielding [this expression](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dtrimas/Published/solns.nb) with complicated conditionals (I added a wolfram cloud link because I couldn't get the expression to paste correctly). This expression looks like

```
{i->3 C[2], If[(*complicated conditional depending on C[1] and C[2]*)], k-> C[2] (47 - 15 f[n]), If[(*complicated conditional depending on C[1] and C[2]*)]}
```

both I and k do not depend on `C[1]`, and I don't understand why mathematica won't remove those conditionals that depend on `C[1]`, so I removed them by hand to get a more reasonable expression:

```
{i -> ConditionalExpression[
   3 C[2], ((1 + (-1)^n == 0 && C[2] < 0) || ((-1)^n == 1 && 
        C[2] > 0)) && C[2] \[Element] Integers ], 
 k -> ConditionalExpression[
   C[2] (47 - 
      15 f[n]), ((1 + (-1)^n == 0 && C[2] < 0) || ((-1)^n == 1 && 
        C[2] > 0)) && C[2] \[Element] Integers]}
```

noticing that `C[2] < 0` when `(-1)^n = -1` and `C[2]>0` when `(-1)^n = 1` we can rewrite this as (for positive integer non zero `C[2]`)

```
{i -> (-1)^n 3 C[2], k -> (-1)^n  C[2] (47 - 15 f[n])}
```

Now the problem is in one variable, and boils down to finding a positive integer `C[2]` s.t. `C[2] (47 - 15 f[n])` is an integer. Since `47 C[2]` is always an integer, we need to find an integer `C[2]` that makes `15 C[2] f[n]` an integer (recall that f[n] is n-1th convergent of Pi here). We can make `C[2]` the denominator of the n-1th convergent, and we are guaranteed to have a solution.

Thus a solution for `(-1) ^ n * (Pi − A002485(n)/A002486(n)) = ((Abs(i)) * 2 ^ j) ^ (-1) * Int((x ^ l * (1 - x) ^ (2 * (j + 2)) * (k + (i + k) * x ^ 2 ))/(1 + x ^ 2 ), x=0 ...1)`
is

```
const[n_] := Denominator@lastConvergent[n];

{j -> 0, l -> 0, {i -> (-1)^(n) 3 const[n], 
 k -> (-1)^n const[n] (47 - 15 lastConvergent[n])}
```

putting this in terms of OEIS sequences (where I assign index 1 to the first element in each sequence, and with integer n>2):

```
{j -> 0, l -> 0, i -> (-1)^(n) 3 A002486[[n + 1]], 
k -> (-1)^(n) (47 A002486[[n + 1]] - 15 A002485[[n + 1]])}
```

The first m+2 terms of A002485 and A002486 can be expressed as:

```
A002485 = Join[{0, 1}, Numerator[Convergents[Pi, m]]];
A002486 = Join[{1, 0}, Denominator[Convergents[Pi, m]]];
```

Comment: Thanks Dear David!  I wish I could award you the bounty but it expired 48 hours ago and I am left with reputation 7 now so I can not even upvote your very helpful answer....

Comment: Dear David - So have I understood your results correctly that the solution <in the form of expressions for parameters "i" and "k" for the subcase when l=j=0 for any n>2 > in conjecture (-1) ^ n * (Pi − A002485(n)/A002486(n)) = ((Abs(i)) * 2 ^ j) ^ (-1) * Int((x ^ l * (1 - x) ^ (2 * (j + 2)) * (k + (i + k) * x ^ 2 ))/(1 + x ^ 2 ), x=0 ...1) is  {i =(-1)^(n) * 3 * A002486[[n + 1]], [[n + 1]], 
k = (-1)^(n) * (47 * A002486[[n + 1]] - 15 * A002485[[n + 1]])} ? Cheers, Alex

Comment: yes but remove this part I believe you may have accidentally typed it twice {i =(-1)^(n) * 3 * A002486[[n + 1]], **[[n + 1]],** k = (-1)^(n) * (47 * A002486[[n + 1]] - 15 * A002485[[n + 1]])}

Comment: You can also get (sometimes) smaller values for {i,k} by calculating the GCD of 15*Numerator@lastConvergent[n] and Denominator@lastConvergent[n] and then dividing Denominator@lastConvergent[n] by the GCD:

`reducedC[n_] := (
  {num, den} = Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[15 lastConvergent[n]]];
  gcd = GCD[num, den];
  den/gcd
  )`

`minRule[n_] := {j -> 0, l -> 0, i -> (-1)^n  * 3 reducedC[n],  k -> (-1)^n *reducedC[n] (47 - 15 lastConvergent[n])}`
for n>2.

Comment: Another thing I was worried about: is this solution actually useful? I feel like maybe it's cheating to have {I,k} in terms of the convergents of Pi, and perhaps it's not what you were looking for.

Comment: Surely it would be better if "i" and "k" would be directly expressible via just "n" rather than as you got it via A002486(n) and A002485(n), but even that (also in spite that your solution is partial just for cases when l=j=0) is still a step forward. By the way I got confused with "n" indexing in your solution - what is the value of "n" should be used to calculate "i" and "k" via A002486(n+1) and A002485(n+1), say, for 22/7?

Comment: @Alex n=3 for 22/7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146370/discussion-between-david-trimas-and-alex).